# Filter Results Server Side Parse while User is typing

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, parse-platform, ionic3, parse-framework

I am using Parse Server and Ionic 3/Angular 4 to build and application. Until, now I was retrieving the users and store them localy and make the filtering on client side with Angular on searchbar while the user is typing a username.

But I think it should be done on Server Side instead to store localy all the users of the database. Like large apps do, like Instagram.

Any idea?

thank you

Comment: Send search text to server and list results. What do you ask exactly?

Comment: If you know for a fact that the data is going to be relatively small, e.g. a short list (~<100)  Its fine to do it on the client side. But If you are expecting a very large list of data, I would strongly recommend doing it on the server side.

Comment: @Andresson of course I want this from client side, because there will be thousands users. But how?

Comment: @omeralper I ask for real time results, while user is typing to get results back

Comment: Same thing. Use settimeout, after few seconds send first letters to the server, fetch strings starting with that chars, and list them in dropdown.

Comment: I want this to work for every charecter is changing and about 700ms. Is that possible?

Comment: If you are familiar with Rxjs they have 2 operators that you might be interested in. 
`.debounceTime(milliseconds)` - .."Discard emitted values that take less than the specified time between output.."  and `.distinctUntilChanged()` - .."Only emit when the current value is different than the last."  
You can read more about rxjs operators [here](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/)

Comment: @Andresson yes i used this to make it on client-side and it was working.  this.searchControl.valueChanges.debounceTime(700).subscribe(search => {
      this.searching = false;
      this.setFilteredItems();
       });

Comment: Is there any tutorial or example how i will filter the results on cloud code?

Comment: What kind of Web API are you using ?

Comment: I am using Parse Server, a very powerful BaaS